# For $a>0$ and $0<x_0<\frac{2}{a}$ let $x_{n+1}=x_n(2-ax_n)$. Show convergence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ and give its limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For $a>0$ and $0<x_0<\frac{2}{a}$ let $x_{n+1}=x_n(2-ax_n)$. Show convergence of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ and give its limit.

Hint: Use $(x_n - \frac{1}{a})$ to show $x_n <\frac{1}{a}$.

---

I'm confused by the notation of this. How am I supposed to find $x_n$ in the first place to test it for convergence? $x_n=2x_{n-1}-ax_{n-1}^2$ … and now?

Comment: Look at $f(x)=2x-ax^2$ where $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ ...

Answer (score 2):

Since we have 
$$1-ax_{n+1}=1-ax_n(2-ax_n)=1-2ax_n+a^2x^2_n=(1-ax_n)^2,$$ this means
$$1-ax_n=(1-ax_0)^{2^n}$$ or
$$x_n=\frac{1-(1-ax_0)^{2^n}}a.$$ The assumption $0<x_0<\frac{2}{a}$ is equivalent with $|1-ax_0|<1$, so we have quadratic convergence of $x_n$ to $\frac1a$.

Answer (score 1):

**just a hint**

Let $f (x)=x (2-ax) $.

its fixed point is such that

$$x=2x-ax^2$$

which gives $x=0$ or $x=\frac {1}{a} $.

$f'(x)=2 (1-ax) \implies  f $ is increasing at $(0,\frac {1}{a}) $.

If $x_0=1/a $ then $x_n=x_0$.

by induction,

If $0 <x_0 <1/a $ then $f (0)<x_n <f (1/a) $.

Answer (score 1):

We will prove convergence by proving the following two claims.

1. Prove $\forall n>0: 0<x_n\le1/a$.
2. Prove that $x_n$ is monotonously increasing.

For claim 1, let us denote a new series $y_n:=a\cdot x_n$.
We will prove Clam 1 by proving an equivalent statement over $y_n$, namely that $\forall n>0: 0<y_n<1$. This is proved by induction on $n$, where for the basis all we know is the weaker: $0<y_0<2$, however, using the AMGM inequality, we get $y_0,(2-y_0)$ are both positive. Hence, $y_1\le(\sqrt{y_0\cdot(2-y_0)})^2\le(\dfrac{y_0+(2-y_0)}{2})^2=1$, positivity is trivial, and the induction step is carried out similarly to the base case.

For claim 2, we use the part of claim 1 that says $y_n$ is positive: Using the $y_n$ notation, we achieved an equivalent formulation which states that:
$$y_{n+1}=y_n(2-y_n)$$ Dividing both sides by $y_n$ allows for: $$\dfrac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}=2-y_n$$ However, substituting $y_n\le 1$ implies: $$\dfrac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}\ge 1$$ This means that $y_n$, and consequentially $x_n$ are monotonically increasing.

Upon proving the two claims we established convergence, and can calculate the limit using the arithmetic of limits as follows:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n(2-ax_n)\implies lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n+1} = lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n(2-ax_n)$$
Denote $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n := L$, then: $L=L(2-L)$, which has two roots, at $L=0$ and $L=1$, however, as $x_n$ is increasing, $L=0$ is impossible, and hence the limit is $L=1$.